# Matching the height of left divs to right divs with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working on a shoppingcart that has the main formalities down the left hand side in separate boxes one under neath the other then on the right hand side i have a thin column I want to put extra recommended products. I would like the height of this right hand sided column to adjust to equal the height of the other divs to the right so they are lined up at the bottom for the footer. All of the divs are position relevant with no set height so that as the content in them changes the whole lot adjusts accordingly, as you add more products etc. Is there a formula I can use to calculate the total height of these divs at any given point and make that height he height of the right div?

EDIT:

Now i have a new problem, the footer doesn't sit underneath the other divs anymore and my adjustable height white box in the background doesn't extend to these either?? with the added js as below in here also from Tim :)

```
     <div class="height-wrapper">
        <div id="yourcartbox" class="height">
            content<br>content<br>content
        </div>
        <div id="yourdetailsbox" class="height">
            content<br>content<br>content
        </div>
        <div id="paymentbox" class="height">
            content<br>content<br>content
        </div>
        <div id="paynowbox" class="height">
            content<br>content<br>content
        </div>
     </div>
     <div id="reccomendedproductsbox" class="rightcolumn>
            content<br>content<br>content
     </div>
     <div id="checkoutfooter"></div>
```

Here is the new css as requested :)

```
    .box {
       width: 678px;
       position: relative;
       border: 1px solid #dde2e6;
       margin-left: 10px;
       padding: 20px;
       margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .height-wrapper {
       float: left;
       position: relative;
    }
    .rightcolumn {
       float: left;
       position: relative;
    }
    #checkoutfooter {
       width: 1024px;
       height: 130px;
       position: relative;
       margin-left: 10px;
       border: 1px solid #26323b;
       background-color: #37434f;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: can you please include the relevant css in your post

Comment: Looks like the widths of left & right columns are too large for the container they're in ... float each in their respective direction & make sure the width + margins doesn't add up to more than the width of the parent. Also, instead of repeating the CSS for each box, just create a `.box` class and apply that to each element in the HTML that shares those attributes:
    `.box{
         width: 678px; 
         position: relative;
         border: 1px solid #dde2e6;
         margin-left: 10px;
         padding: 20px;
         margin-bottom: 10px;
    }`

Comment: @mc01 i have updated my question with your suggestions :) thanks heaps! Now posing a new problem though :/

Comment: Don't worry i fixed up the css so only the .height-wrapper has the float left then added a left margin to the .rightcolumn and now its all fitting in perfectly. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d74zLncx/) for you.

You could get the height of the left column on load and set it on the right column using jQuery `.height()`. Just wrap the div's with class `.height` in a div with class `.height-wrapper` and you should be good to go.

```
$(window).on('load', function () {

  target = $('.height-wrapper').height();
  $('.rightcolumn').height(target);

});
```

Comment: Thanks! @Tim! Will try this now, i reckon that will work tho :)

Comment: this is working great for the height except it is out by 2px... i think its adding the border from the top and bottom to the new height of right column, how do i add in a -2px thing to the equation, i tried googling but couldn't see an example of the structure. @Tim

Comment: Try `.height(target + -2)`. But, don't you think you can find a css solution? Although this will work, I don't mind having a look if you can reproduce the problem in a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Ive made some changes to your css namely adding a wrapper to the left column and floating the columns left. No need for javascript.

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmsdte3o/)**

```
body {min-width:1000px}

.leftcolumn{float:left; width: 500px;}

#reccomendedproductsbox {
       width: 336px;
       float: left;
       border: 1px solid #dde2e6;
       margin-left:20px;
       padding: 20px;
       margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#yourcartbox {


       border: 1px solid #dde2e6;
       margin-left: 10px;
       padding: 20px;
       margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#yourdetailsbox {

       border: 1px solid #dde2e6;
       margin-left: 10px;
       padding: 20px;
       margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#paymentbox {

       border: 1px solid #dde2e6;
       margin-left: 10px;
       padding: 20px;
       margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#paynowbox {

       border: 1px solid #dde2e6;
       margin-left: 10px;
       padding: 20px;
       margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```